# (real analysis) How is it possible?

Tags: real-analysis

I should prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^2_n=a^2$ if ${a_n}$ is a sequence in $R$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$.

So, because $a_n$ is convergent, ${a_n}$ is bounded, i.e. $\exists M>0\ s.t. |a_n|<M$ for all $n\in N$.

Then, $|a^2_n-a^2|=|a_n-a||a_n+a|$.

I found that $|a^2_n-a^2|=|a_n-a||a_n+a|<2M|a_n-a|$.

But, I can't understand why $|a_n+a|<2M$.

If $|a_n|<M$, I wonder if is possible that $|a|<M$

Comment: Actually, it holds $|a| \le M$. Suppose otherwise, so $|a| \ge M + \delta$ for some $\delta>0$. Then $|a_n - a| \ge \delta$ (check it!), contradicting $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$.

Comment: Since $I=[0,M]$ is closed, if $a_n \in I$ for all $n$ and $a_n \to a$ then $a \in I$.

Comment: if $|a_n|<M$ $\forall n$ then also $|a|<M$

Comment: @TheStudent That's nonsense. Consider $a_n=1-\frac1n$ and $M=1$.

Comment: People have pointed out that in fact $|a|\le M$. Nobody's pointed out _explicitly_that $|a|\le M$ is enough to make your proof work...

Comment: This is because @PhilliP didn't ask that.

Comment: You could have also just said that $$|a^2_n-a^2|=|a_n-a||a_n+a|<(|a| + M)|a_n-a|.$$ All that is important here is that $|a_n + a|$ is bounded. It doesn't matter what that bound is.

Comment: so.. in short, it is nonsense that $|a_n|<M$ means $|a|<M$, right? Then how can I prove this one? Is it okay to choose $n_0  s.t. |a_n-a|<\epsilon/(|a|+M+1)$? @TheStudent

Comment: @PhilliP that is not my comment.

Comment: so.. in short, it is nonsense that |an|<M means |a|<M, right? Then how can I prove this one? Is it okay to choose n0s.t.|an−a|<ϵ/(|a|+M+1)? @PaulSinclair

Comment: @TheStudent should have said "$|a_n| < M \implies |a| \le M$". Whether they were unaware that equality is possible, or just careless in their typesetting, I cannot say. All this proof requires is showing that $|a_n^2 - a^2| \le K|a_n - a|$ for some constant $K$. Since $|a_n| < M$, it is easy to show $|a_n + a| < |a| + M$, so $K = |a| + M$ works. But if you already know the result TheStudent almost got right, then you can use it to show $K = 2M$ also works. Any larger $K$ would also work.